# What is Tara Tam's ethnicity?

Tags: marvel, howard-the-duck

In Chip Zdarsky's 2015 run of *Howard the Duck*, the primary supporting character is Tara Tam, a millennial tattoo artist that becomes acquainted with Howard and accompanies him throughout some of his adventures. Depending on who the artist is, she appears to have a different skin color. Have either of the character's creators, Zdarsky or Joe Quinones, given a definitive answer as to what ethnicity Tara Tam is supposed to be?

[image]

Comment: The surname Tam is mainly associated with Vietnam and Malaysia. It's also extremely common in China

Comment: I'm not a big Howard the Duck follower but IMHO she looks very Malay or at least SE Asian.

Comment: I have twitted at the creators. Hopefully they'll weigh in with an answer.